# Get a field setting in hook_form_alter()

Tags: 8, hooks

Is it possible to get all fields of a specific type in hook_form_alter?

By fields I mean an array of something that contains each fields name and settings.

The reason why I want it in `hook_form_alter` is that I need to add a property to the form tag that depends on field setting, using `$form['#attributes']`.

Is there another/better way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of form you have and which field settings do you mean? Is there another way? Yes, in Drupal there are always other ways. In a form alter hook you can do anything, but more in a chaotic way. So there is no real guideline. You have to look what you've get in the hook arguments to tell. And this will be *very* different dependent on the kind of form you have.